# generate php array from database while loop

Tags: php

I want to generate exactly same array from database data which I am getting from while loop which will be passed to some other function and it does not accept anything else.

When i pass this data manually it works so it should be exactly same.

```
$putArray7 =array
(

      //  "title" => "Test Product " ,
      //  "body_html" => "test description" ,
        "images" => array
        (
        array(
              "id" => "6800163209265",
              "attachment" => "$attachment_base64",
        ),
        array(
              "id" => "6800163438641",
              "attachment" => "$attachment_base64",
        ),
        array(
              "id" => "6800164880433",
              "attachment" => "$attachment_base64",
        ),

 )

   );
```

What i tried:

```
  $response99 = array();
  $response_final = array();
// data from mysql starts here 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))

 {
      $response99[] = ['id'=>$id_img_id .',', 
  'attachment'=>$attachment_base64];

   }
```

Now tried to recreate whole array here:

```
// did not work 

     $response_final[] = ['title'=>"Test Product 53","body_html" => "test description" , 'images'=>$response99];
```

Tried this:

```
    $response_final[] = ['title'=>"Test Product 53","body_html" => "test description" , 'images'=>[$response99]];
```

This one also did not work:

Tried several other ways. Any help will be great.

Want to generate exactly like `$putArray7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$response99 = array();
$response_final = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $a = array();
    $a['id'] = $row['id'];
    $a['attachment'] = $row['attachment'];
    $response99[] = $a;
}
$response_final = array(
    'title' => "Test Product 53",
    'body_html' => "test description" ,
    'images' => $response99
);
```